# Data line not matching regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, parsing, pattern-matching

I'm trying to parse lines of data using the following pattern:

> 1337;GROUP;VARIABLE;13.37;key=value;key=value;key=value ...(and so on)

It's basically `Number?;Name?;Name?;Value;(key=value)*`.

The `;` separator can be set to any string. For instance, if it's set to `FOO`, this line of data would be considered valid:

> 1337FOOGROUPFOOVARIABLEFOO13.37FOOkey=value

Since only the `Value` is mandatory, this line would also be considered valid:

> FOOFOOFOO13.37

I've tried the following test code:

```
private static final String BASE_PAYLOAD_DATA = "\\s*(\\d*SEPNOTSEP*SEPNOTSEP*SEPNOTSEP+(?:SEPNOTSEP*=NOTSEP*)*)\\s*$";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "1337;GROUP;VARIABLE;13.37;key=value";
    String separator = ";";

    String processed = StringUtils.replace(BASE_PAYLOAD_DATA, "NOTSEP", "(?!" + separator + ")");
    processed = StringUtils.replace(processed, "SEP", "(?:" + separator + ")");
    System.out.println(processed);

    Pattern payloadData = Pattern.compile(processed);
    System.out.println(payloadData.matcher(line).matches());
}
```

but the tested line does not match. The `SEP` and `NOTSEP` strings are used to simulate the fact that the separator can be configured.

Output:

```
\s*(\d*(?:;)(?!;)*(?:;)(?!;)*(?:;)(?!;)+(?:(?:;)(?!;)*=(?!;)*)*)\s*$
false
```

I've double and triple checked the pattern, but I can't seem to point out the faulty element, and I fear I might be missing something way too obvious.

Or is there a behaviour about the non-recording and the negative look-ahead groups I am missing?

Also, is there a more elegant way to declare the regex pattern?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

It seems that from this [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> The lookahead itself is not a capturing group. It is not included in the count towards numbering the backreferences. If you want to store the match of the regex inside a lookahead, you have to put capturing parentheses around the regex inside the lookahead, like this: (?=(regex)).

I'll give it a shot.

Comment: try using regex101.com

Comment: @Andrew Interesting, I did not know about that tool.
It's telling me `Preceding token is not quantifiable` for every negative look-ahead group. Why can't those be quantified?

Comment: `\s*(\d*(?:;)(?!;)\*(?:;)(?!;)\*(?:;)(?!;)\+(?:(?:;)(?!;)\*=(?!;)\*)*)\s*$`

Comment: That's totally looks like CSV - why do you want to use regex here?

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov It is indeed CSV with a configurable separator, but these lines of data all have a common pattern and I want to only take the lines that respect this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrounding the negative look-ahead groups with a non-capturing group each made them quantifiable, as I linked in my edit ([Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html:)):

> The lookahead itself is not a capturing group. It is not included in the count towards numbering the backreferences. If you want to store the match of the regex inside a lookahead, you have to put capturing parentheses around the regex inside the lookahead, like this: (?=(regex)).

I finally decided to use a less restrictive regex, split the lines with the separator and analyze the tokens with a more Java-based approach (compare tokens, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think you assumed that (?!X) 'negative lookahead for semicolon' is the same as 'not semicolon' [^;].
Just by curiosity why do you use (?:;) which is non-capturing group instead just ;?
I think this could be helpful for you [Java SE 7 Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: `The ; separator can be set to any string`